# Prevent different users simultaneously data entry in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

My spreadsheet acts as a sales tool, where info is entered in various cells to run sensitivity analysis. Once the salesperson picks a desired option they "submit it". The data submitted is then stored on a separate sheet in the spreadsheet (call it the "database").

I want the database sheet to store all user submissions. The problem is when multiple users are using the sales tool worksheet at the same time, the info they enter gets overwritten by other user's inputs before they can submit.

I'd like multiple users to be able to use the "sales tool" sheet simultaneously without overwriting eachother, but still be able to submit data to the "database" sheet.

For Reference, [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M8IZgQdz0qR8JeklS_lyYnKCVMjKiOVzj1ZHU7QWgkA/edit?usp=sharing) is spreadsheet.
And [Here](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1A_AuWhb7exU3nbOKKVuGEfvMkWLyofRxngiVn7FGRzT25v7wxTgacnp-/edit) is App Script.

```js
function submitData() {
     
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 

  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("User Feedback form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Feedback form worksheet

  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet

  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit the data?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects Yes
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
  {return;//exit from this function
  } 
 
  //Validating the entry. If validation is true then proceed with transferring the data to Database sheet
 //if (validateEntry()==true) {

    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue()); //POD Lead Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F4").getValue()); //Member Email
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue()); //FT Score
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C8").getValue()); //BT Score
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C10").getValue()); //SI Score
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue()); //CI Score
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C14").getValue());//ED Score
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F6").getValue()); //FT feedback
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F8").getValue()); //BT feedback
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F10").getValue()); //SI feedback
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F12").getValue()); //CI feedback
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F14").getValue());//ED feedback
   
    // date function to update the current date and time as submittted on
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 14).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd'); //Submitted On
    
    //get the email address of the person running the script and update as Submitted By
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By
    
    ui.alert(' "Feedback Saved' + shUserForm.getRange("F4").getValue() +' "');
  
  //Clearnign the data from the Data Entry Form

   shUserForm.getRange("C4").clear(); //POD Lead Name
  shUserForm.getRange("F4").clear();//Member Email
  shUserForm.getRange("C6").clear(); //FT Score
  shUserForm.getRange("C8").clear(); //BT Score
  shUserForm.getRange("C10").clear(); //SI Score
  shUserForm.getRange("C12").clear(); //CI Score
  shUserForm.getRange("C14").clear();//ED Score
  shUserForm.getRange("F6").clear(); //FT feedback
  shUserForm.getRange("F8").clear(); //BT feedback
  shUserForm.getRange("F10").clear(); //SI feedback
  shUserForm.getRange("F12").clear(); //CI feedback
  shUserForm.getRange("F14").clear();//ED feedback
      
 //}
}
```

Comment: In the case of `The problem is when multiple users are using the sales tool worksheet at the same time, the info they enter gets overwritten by other user's inputs before they can submit.`, the users are manually editing the cells, while the current values are used by "submit". By this, the values with "submit" are changed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, can you provide the script of "submit"? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with App Script. You can see the last submitData function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of the link of the script, other users cannot see it. So I added it to your question. And, from your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: How detailed/complex is the information that the sales person is submitting? Could you create a google form that would deal with the entry of the infromation, this could then change the process so you dont need to use code in anyway for the protection of the cells

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about protecting the sheets when the function `submitData()` is run? And, when the script of `submitData()` is finished, the protects are removed. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

This is your current script of submitData()`submitData()`.

```
function submitData() {

  // This is your current script.

}
```

##### To

Please rename the function name as follows.

```
function submitData_org() {

  // This is your current script.

}
```

And, please add the following function.

```
function submitData() {
  const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(350000)) {
    try {
      const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
      sheets.forEach(s => {
        const p = s.protect();
        p.removeEditors(p.getEditors());
        p.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
      })

      submitData_org(); // Here, your script is called.

      sheets.forEach(s => s.protect().remove());
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("timeout");
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when `submitData()` is run, the sheets are protected, and when your script of `submitData_org()` is finished, the protects are removed. This flow is run with the LockService.

#### References:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: Thank you. How about protecting the sheets for other users when one user is filling out data? Like in this way another user will not able to change the data that one user is filling out.

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I want to say that when multiple users are using the worksheet at the same time, the info they enter gets overwritten by other user's inputs before they can submit. How about we protect sheets until one user submits data. In this way data will not overwritten by other user's inputs.

Comment: hey there @user8702720! have you tried this solution, if so, what does not work as expected? would you simply like to protect the sheet for each separate user?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It is not working. I want that when one person is editing/adding information in a sheet. Protect that sheet for another person.

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I want that when one person is editing/adding information in a sheet. Protect that sheet for another person.`, in my proposed script, when the script is run, the sheets are protected from other users. But when you are the owner of the Spreadsheet, you can continue to edit. Please be careful about this. So I cannot understand your reply. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the detail of `It is not working.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the script runs when submit button is clicked. I want only one user to add/edit information at a time. Protect sheet for other users. Please have a look at the above reference spreadsheet.

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Actually, the script runs when submit button is clicked. I want only one user to add/edit information at a time. Protect sheet for other users.`, in my proposed script, when the script is run, only the owner and the user who clicked the button can edit the sheets. In this case, other users cannot edit. But the owner can always edit even when the sheets are protected. It seems that this is the current specification of the protection. I deeply apologize for this specification.